# How to plot a cartesian equation with SymPy?

Tags: python, plot, sympy, cartesian-coordinates

How to plot a cartesian equation with SymPy? 
For example how to plot

```
x*(x+y) + 2*x^3 + x^4 + y^4 == 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit):

```py
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols("x, y")
plot_implicit(x * (x + y) + 2 * x**3 + x**4 + y**4)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks you very much ^^